# Text to Speech using Processing IDE

Tags: android, processing, text-to-speech

I'm new in Android programming. I want to add TTS features in my android app. I'm using Processing IDE (Im using this tutorial because its easy to understand http://arduinobasics.blogspot.com.au/2013/03/arduino-basics-bluetooth-android.html)

can anyone help me give some example or demo codes for TTS in Processing? I think the important part is to initialized the TTS for it to be used in the application. I've search but all I find is example code use in Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Nikolaus Gradwohl's ttslib might be exactly what you're looking for. However, there seem to have been some issues with halting the draw() function, although I'm not sure if they're fixed yet. To prevent this, run it in a new Thread as show on [this](http://forum.processing.org/one/topic/ttslib-speaking-halts-drawing.html) forum post.

[Here](http://www.local-guru.net/blog/pages/ttslib) is the entire documentation for the ttslib. To install it, go to Sketch>Import Library>Add Library and search for ttslib.

[Here](http://blogspot.tenettech.com/?p=518) is a good resource for using Processing and the tts library to read out data from an Arduino's potentiometer.

Comment: I try  the guru.ttslib.I try using the guru.ttslib but everytime I add it in my code, there will always a BUILD error. If I dont add it in the code, everything will run smoothly. "Error in the Android Console"